# Resolve const and non-const member function pointer

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

In the below code snippet, I want to be able to call `A::foo` from `doWork`.

However because there are two overloads of `foo`( `const` and non-`const` ), compiler is unable to resolve which one I mean in call of `doWork`.
Is there a way to tell compiler that I meant which one.

I cannot change `struct A`.

Can I do something in signature of doWork or call of doWork to always pick say the const one.

One solution I know is to give function pointer type as argument of `doWork` instead of the template(like this)
`void doWork(void (A::*fun)(void) const){`
But this is little ugly and I wish to find a template based solution(if one exists)

```
struct A{
    void foo() const {
    }
    void foo(){
    }
    void bar(){
    }
    void bar() const {
    }
};

template<typename F>
void doWork(F fun){
    const A a;
    (a.*fun)();
}

int main()
{
    doWork(&A::foo); //error: no matching function for call to ‘doWork()’
    doWork(&A::bar); // error: no matching function for call to ‘doWork()’
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use:

```
template <typename T>
void doWork(void (T::*fun)() const){
    const A a;
    (a.*fun)();
}
```

A more generic function template would use `const T a`.

```
template <typename T>
void doWork(void (T::*fun)() const){
    const T a;
    (a.*fun)();
}
```

Note that the second version does not assume `A` anywhere.

Comment: Accepted this answer, as this keeps the call of `doWork` cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast#Notes) to specify which one should be used.

> `static_cast` may also be used to disambiguate function overloads by
>   performing a function-to-pointer conversion to specific type, as in
>
> ```
> std::for_each(files.begin(), files.end(),
>               static_cast<std::ostream&(*)(std::ostream&)>(std::flush));
> ```

e.g.

```
doWork(static_cast<void (A::*)(void) const>(&A::foo));
doWork(static_cast<void (A::*)(void) const>(&A::bar));
```

Or specify the template argument explicitly.

```
doWork<void (A::*)(void) const>(&A::foo);
doWork<void (A::*)(void) const>(&A::bar);
```