# Generic way of getting pointer to member const overload without explicit cast

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-meta-programming

I have seen the following topic:
[Resolve const and non-const member function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58315258/resolve-const-and-non-const-member-function-pointer)

But I wonder if there's a generic-programming friendly way of doing it as of C++11 or newer.
For the sake of example, imagine the following class:

```cpp
struct S
{
    int v = 42;
    int& value() { return v;}
    int value() const {return v;}
};
```

the following helper class

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Holder
{
    using TYPE = T;
};
```

However when I try this:

```cpp
    auto l = [](auto holder) 
        -> decltype(&(std::add_const_t<typename decltype(holder)::TYPE>::value))
        {
            return &(std::add_const_t<typename decltype(holder)::TYPE>::value);
        };
```

I keep getting the following error from GCC:
`error: 'decltype' cannot resolve address of overloaded function`
while clang just crashes during compilation.

Why is that, if:

```cpp
  static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<
        const S, 
        std::add_const_t<Holder<std::decay_t<S>>::TYPE>>, 
    "");
```

https://godbolt.org/z/e5E7Ts156

Should that be the case, or have I bumped into a weird defect/corner case?

Comment: There is no such thing as `&(const S)::value` in C++. Class members belong to the class (i.e. `S`) not to the type (ie. `const S`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
template <typename Owner, typename Ret, typename... Arg>
constexpr auto getConstFuncPtr(Ret (Owner::*mfpc)(Arg...) const) { return mfpc; }

template <typename Owner, typename Ret, typename... Arg>
constexpr auto getNonConstFuncPtr(Ret (Owner::*mfpnc)(Arg...)) { return mfpnc; }

auto mfpc  = getConstFuncPtr(&S::value);
auto mfpnc = getNonConstFuncPtr(&S::value);
```

There is an implicit conversion (which is not a cast) that helps decide which function to take.